# Finding out version of a jar file

Tags: jar, version

I am new to working with jar files. I have been given a jar file and need to find out what version it is. How is that possible ?

```
qpid-jms-client.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the `.jar` with some archiving software like WinWar and finding a version file.

In your case if you open it and go to `org/apache/qpid/jms/version.txt` you will see the version.